# Adding shapes to JPanel on a button click

Tags: java, swing, paint

I have a Class Circle with a button and a Class with a jPanel what i want to do is when that button is clicked a circle will be drawn on the panel and each time i click that button and change x and y "some how not implemented here" i got a circle on the JPanel over and over .
How to do that, or is there a way to do what i descriped regardless of my code but i want the class circle to extends  Shape.

```
public class Window{

  private JFrame frame;
  private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  Circle c = new Circle(frame, panel);
  // some other buttons 
  .
  .
 // some code to set the panel grid bag constaraints and background then
 frame.getContentPane().add(panel, gbc_panel);
}
```

then the Circle Class

```
public class Circle extends Shape implements ActionListener{

  private JPanel Panel;
  private GridBagConstraints gbc_btnCircle;
  private JButton btnCircle;

  public void setPanel(JPanel panel) {
      Panel = panel;
  }

 public Circle(JFrame frame, JPanel panel){
    btnCircle = new JButton("Circle");
    // some code to set grid bag constraint then
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnCircle, gbc_btnCircle);
    setPanel(panel);        
    btnCircle.addActionListener(this);

 }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponents(g);
      g.setColor(Color.red);        
      g.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);     
      Panel.add(this);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    repaint();      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You kinda have the wrong idea. In your drawing panel, you should have a `List<Circle>`. And in the `paintComponent` method of the drawing panel, you should iterate through the list to draw each circle

```
class Circle {
    int x, int y, int width, int height;
    public Circle (int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        ... set em
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    List<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Circle circle : circles) {
            circle.draw(g);
        }
    }

    // Dont forget to override public Dimension getPreferredSize()
}
```

To add more Circles to the list, just have a `addCircle` method in the `DrawingPanel` class

```
public void addCircle(Circle circle) {
    circles.add(circle);
    repaint();
}
```

As far as the button, you should be creating it in the `Window` class. In the `ActionListener`, just create a `new Circle` and add it the `DrawingPanel` by calling the `addCircle` method

---

An aside, `Circle` doesn't need the extend `Shape`. The `Shape` API already has an [`Ellipse2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html) class, which you can create circles from

```
class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    List<Ellipse2D> circles = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        for (Ellipse2D circle : circles) {
            g2.fill(circle);
        }
        g2.dispose();
    }
    // Dont forget to override public Dimension getPreferredSize()
}
```

- See [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)

---

**UPDATE: full example**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CirclesDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new CirclesDemo();
            }
        });
    }

    public CirclesDemo() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.add(createButton(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private final DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel();

    private JButton createButton() {
        JButton button = new JButton("Add Circle");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int[] circleValues = generateRandomValues(300, 300, 50, 150);
                int x = circleValues[0];
                int y = circleValues[1];
                int width = circleValues[2];
                int height = width;
                Circle circle = new Circle(x, y, width, height);
                panel.addCircle(circle);
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

    private int[] generateRandomValues(int maxX, int maxY, 
                                       int minSize, int maxSize) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] values = new int[3];
        values[0] = random.nextInt(maxX);
        values[1] = random.nextInt(maxY);
        values[2] = Math.min(random.nextInt(maxSize) + minSize, maxSize);
        return values;
    }

    class Circle {

        int x, y, width, height;

        public Circle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public void draw(Graphics g) {
            g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }

    class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        List<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (Circle circle : circles) {
                circle.draw(g);
            }
        }

        public void addCircle(Circle circle) {
            circles.add(circle);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would you please look add the edits and till me why i still doesn't work? i got nothing on my panel when i click the button.

Comment: 1) I don't see where the button is created and where you add the `ActionListener`. I'm going to assume to completely ditched the first Circle class 2) Did you override `getPreferredSize`? 3) I don't see you adding the `DrawingPanel` to the frame.

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the paint method of Circle. You need to be overriding the paint method of the panel.

Comment: How to do that, please?