# Drawing circle inside an existing JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have followed peeskillet and changed my codes according to his last idea. Here are the changed codes

**CriclePanel class**

```
    public class CirclePanel extends JPanel {
    int centerX, centerY, radius;
    Color circle_color;

    public void setCircle(int centerX, int centerY, int radius, Color c) {
        this.centerX = centerX;
        this.centerY = centerY;
        this.radius = radius;
        circle_color = c;
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("Trying to draw circle");
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillOval(centerX, centerY, radius*2, radius*2);
    }
}
```

**Grid Panel (added from palette and custom constructed)**

```
myGridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8,8));
panels = new CirclePanel[8][8];
    for (int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < panels[i].length; j++) {
            CirclePanel panel = new CirclePanel();
            panels[i][j] = panel;
            myGridPanel.add(panel);
        }
    }
```

**Trying to add draw circle:**

```
if(dType==DiceType.blackDice){
            System.err.println("black @"+i+","+j);
            panels[i][j].setCircle(x, y, radius, Color.BLACK);
        }else{
            System.err.println("white @"+i+","+j);
            panels[i][j].setCircle(x, y, radius, Color.WHITE);
        }
```

But the circles are not drawn on the grid panel and there is no grid also on the mother panel "myGridPanel". I am seeing that the paintComponant() of CirclePanel is not being called.

Output: http://s25.postimg.org/v8u398dun/no_Gridnd_Circle.png

Comment: Look into [Refining the Design](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/refining.html) to not make the Circles panels

Comment: Another thing, if you are going to add panels at runtime, you need to reavalidate and repaint the container, but keep in mind, adding panels in top of the grid panel will cause the grid lines to not show. You would have to make each circle panel not opaque. Also you're going to have a difficult time trying to lay them out. I would just follow the link above, and do some refactoring

Comment: Cant understand @peeskillet. Could you help a bit more with modifiying my code?

Comment: Follow the link. Forget the whole second comment. Basiacally what I'm saying is to not make each a Circle a panel. The link will show what I mean

Comment: Also [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26678968/2587435)

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can [Refine your Design](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/refining.html) by not making every `Circle` a panel. Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26678968/2587435)

Another option that would fit for your *current* design, would be to have a setter in each circle panel, for which you can pass a circle model.

```
public class CirclePanel extends JPanel {
    private Circle circle;

    public void setCircle(Circle cirlce) {
        this.circle = circle;
        repaint();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (circle != null) {
            // get the state from circle and paint
            g.fillOval(circle.getX(), circle.getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

Note: `Circle` in this case **is not a panel**

Then for the `gridPanel` give it a `GridLayout` and add all the `CirclePanel` to it.

```
JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 5));
CirclePanel[][] panels = new CirclePanel[5][5];
for (int i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < panels[i].length; j++) {
        CirclePanel panel = new CirclePanel();
        panels[i][j] = panel;
        gridPanels.add(panel);
    }
}
```

Doing this, there will be empty `CirclePanel` in the `gridPanel`. Then when you want to paint a circle in one of the panels, you can do something like

```
Circle circle = new Circle(...);
panels[1][1].setCircle(circle);
```

---

**UPDATE**

Or now that I think about it, you don't even really need a `Circle` class, since you could just draw the circle a `0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()`. You could simple set a flag to draw. But if you want to add more state to the circle, then maybe you *could* keep a circle class. But if not, it might look something like

```
public class CirclePanel extends JPanel {
    private boolean draw;
    private Color color;

    // setter for color
    // setter for draw

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (draw) {
            // get the state from circle and paint
            g.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Update with example

See the method `setDraw`. That's where I set the flag the draw or not draw. I call it in the mouse listener in the `Circle` class, but you can call it from anywhere.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CircleDemo {
    private static final int GRID_SIZE = 5;
    private Circle[][] circlePanels 
            = new Circle[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];
    private JPanel gridPanel 
            = new JPanel(new GridLayout(GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE));

    public CircleDemo() {
        initCircles();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.add(gridPanel);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initCircles() {
        for (int i = 0; i < circlePanels.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < circlePanels[i].length; j++) {
                Circle circle = new Circle();
                circlePanels[i][j] = circle;
                gridPanel.add(circle);
            }
        }
    }

    class Circle extends JPanel {
        private boolean draw = false;
        private Color color = Color.BLUE;

        public Circle() {
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (isDraw()) {
                        setDraw(false);
                    } else {
                        setDraw(true);
                    }  
                }
            });
        }

        public boolean isDraw() {
            return draw;
        }

        public void setDraw(boolean draw) {
            this.draw = draw;
            repaint();
        }

        public void setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(75, 75);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (draw) {
                g.setColor(color);
                g.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new CircleDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have taken your 2nd suggestion and changed my codes. Still to no avail. Circles are not being drawn and no grid also

Comment: The suggestion in the **UPDATE**? Did you create a method `setDraw(boolean)`, and set the `draw` value and `repaint()`? Also did you add all the panels to the grid from the start. The update portion was actually a combination of the two. I'll post an example shortly

Comment: See my recent update. When you run it, just click on a cell to make the circle appear, and click it again to make it disappear