# Adding a method draw() to custom shape classes

Tags: java, swing, methods, jframe

This is a bonus question on my homework assignment.

The title says it all, I've built custom shape classes and need to define the draw() method for each one and I'm having a bit of trouble finding a good source tutorial for how to go about doing this.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

This explains exactly what I'm attempting to do but there's no guidance beyond what I already had so if anyone has any additional sources that I can utilize, I'd really appreciate the links.

As far as what I currently have:

```
abstract public void draw();
```

I've defined my draw function in my Shape class like so, and within each of my inherited shapes I've put:

```
public void draw(){}
```

So they currently do nothing. That is where my problem lies. I'm not sure where to continue from here, as far as actual implementations go, for instructing the shape to draw onto the jframe window and additionally, how I will eventually call the functions themselves in order to draw them on the actual window.

Any links, sources or other posts are more than welcome as my brain is rather mushy right now.

Thanks!

Edit 1: So looking over the typical 2D graphics stuff I realized I couldn't use the normal implementations because of how my shapes are made. They're constructed using a Point reference and then built based on those points, so for instance my Circle looks something like this:

```
class Circle extends Shape{
private static final double PI = Math.PI;
private Point point;
private double radius;

public Circle (Point p, double rad){
    point = p;
    radius = rad;
}
}
```

So I'm not able to use the normal oval(int,int,int,int) format. Sorry for not including this earlier, brain mush.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/refining.html). Basically your draw method should accept a Graphics objects from which you will call this method from a paintComponent and pass in the Graphics context from the paintComponent method. Another example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26678968/2587435)

Comment: `abstract public void draw();` should probably be `abstract public void draw(Graphics g);`.  Then in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of the custom painting panel, iterate the collection of shapes and call `currentshape.draw(g);`..

Comment: You probably want a Graphics object as an argument to your draw method.

Comment: Those were all great sources! Thanks a ton for the help guys! I should hopefully be able to finish this up now.

Comment: When you're done, you should post a snippet of what you did (and a little explanation to go with) to get it work. Just for other future readers :-)

Comment: I've hit a bit of a snag and looking back it's something I should have included with my original post so I'm going to add it up there.

Comment: Why can't you get `x, y` from `Point` and `width, height` from the calculations on the `rad`. Use those four to `g.fillOval(x,y,width,height)` in your circle `draw` method.